# ¿Cómo rellenar List<> de mi modelo en JS?

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, web, razor

Estoy trabajando con una aplicacion web en c# y estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de agregar a mi modelo el contenido de un listado.

Mi controlador tiene los siguientes métodos:

```
public IActionResult Formulario()
       {
            VM_Formulario vm = new VM_Formulario();

            vm.guardar = true;

            return View("Formulario", vm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Formulario(VM_Formulario vm)
        {
            return View("Formulario", vm);
        }
```

El VM_Formulario contiene:

```
public class VM_Formulario
    {
        public VM_Formulario()
        {
            l_usuarios = new List<Usuario>();
        }
        public bool guardar { get; set; }
        public List<Usuario> l_usuarios { get; set; }
    }
```

El Modelo Usuario contiene:

```
public class Usuario
    {
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public int edad { get; set; }
    }
```

Mi problema viene en el html:

```
@model PruebaList.Models.VM_Formulario

@using (Html.BeginForm("Formulario", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.l_usuarios)

    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.guardar)

    <input type="submit" value="guardar" />
    
    <button id="generar">Generar usuario random</button>

}

<script>
    var button, contenedor;

    window.onload = () => {
        button = document.getElementById("generar");

        button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

            e.preventDefault();

            var nombre = "Usuario";
            var edad = 99;

            var nuevoUsuario = {
                nombre: nombre,
                edad: edad
            };

        })

    }
</script>
```

Quiero que al generar ese nuevo usuario se vaya guardadno en l_usuarios pero en el controlador me aparece vacío. Muchas gracias

Comment: Pero en tu función javascript no agregas nada al formulario ¿Como esperas que llegue algo?

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/609855/301324